# TikZ: Place a text node in the middle of a cycled path

Tags: tikz-pgf, positioning

I have drawn an arrow using a cycled path. I want to put a text node in the middle (relatively to *x* and *y* axis).

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
    \usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \draw (4,0.25) -- ++(0,2.5) -- ++(-.25,0) -- ++(.5,.5) -- ++(.5,-.5) --++(-.25,0) -- ++(0,-2.5) -- cycle;
        \node at (4.25,1.5) [rotate=90, anchor=center] {\textbf{here!}};
        \draw (6,0.25) -- ++(0,2.5) -- ++(-.25,0) -- ++(.5,.5) -- ++(.5,-.5) --++(-.25,0) -- ++(0,-2.5) -- cycle node [pos=.5, rotate=90] {not there};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

I have tried **`pos=.5`** (as in `\draw (0,0) rectangle (1,1) node [pos=.5] {here!};`) and **`midway`** (as in `\draw (0,0) -- (1,1) node [midway] {here!};`) but it doesn't work...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to put node at right path ...

[image]

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.arrows}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \draw (4,0.25) -- ++(0,2.5) -- ++(-.25,0) -- ++(.5,.5) -- ++(.5,-.5) --++(-.25,0) -- ++(0,-2.5) -- cycle;
        \node at (4.25,1.5) [rotate=90, anchor=center] {\textbf{here!}};

        \draw (6,0.25) -- node [text=red, sloped,below=-0.5pt] {I'm here} ++ (0,2.5) -- ++(-.25,0) -- ++(.5,.5) -- ++(.5,-.5) --++(-.25,0) -- ++(0,-2.5) -- cycle;

       \node[single arrow, draw, text=blue,
  minimum height=30mm, single arrow head extend=2.5mm,
  rotate=90,anchor=west]   at (8,0.25) {I'm in node};

    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

However, see if use of shape `single arrow` (package `shapes.arrows`) better fit your needs. Example of its use is added (far right arrow).

Comment: Indeed, the `shapes.arrows` library addresses my needs for this particular example! Thank you. I'd like however to be able to do the same for more "exotic" shapes... in that sense, Solution #3 cannot apply, and #2 is not fully satisfactory, since I've to manually define the node (and it doesn't update if I change arrow width).